# How to get the first value of each group in CnosDB?

Tags: cnosdb

I have some data in cnosdb and I want to get the **first value** in each group.

My data is like:

```
> SELECT * FROM cpu;
+---------------------+------+--------------+
| time                | cpu  | usage_system |
+---------------------+------+--------------+
| 2023-08-11T11:00:00 | cpu0 | 0.1          |
| 2023-08-11T11:00:00 | cpu1 | 0.2          |
| 2023-08-11T11:01:00 | cpu0 | 0.3          |
| 2023-08-11T11:01:00 | cpu1 | 0.4          |
| 2023-08-11T11:02:00 | cpu0 | 0.5          |
| 2023-08-11T11:02:00 | cpu1 | 0.6          |
+---------------------+------+--------------+
```

I want to get data set like this:

```
+---------------------+------+--------------------+
| time                | cpu  | first_usage_system |
+---------------------+------+--------------------+
| 2023-08-11T11:00:00 | cpu0 | 0.1                |
| 2023-08-11T11:00:00 | cpu1 | 0.2                |
+---------------------+------+--------------------+
```

I found function `FIRST_VALUE` in the [document](http://localhost:8080/zh/latest/reference/sql.html#first-value), but it cannot solve my problem.

```
## This sql returns data for each column.
> SELECT time, cpu, FIRST_VALUE(usage_system) OVER(PARTITION BY cpu ORDER BY usage_system) as first_usage_system from cpu;
+---------------------+------+--------------------+
| time                | cpu  | first_usage_system |
+---------------------+------+--------------------+
| 2023-08-11T11:00:00 | cpu0 | 0.1                |
| 2023-08-11T11:00:00 | cpu1 | 0.2                |
| 2023-08-11T11:01:00 | cpu0 | 0.1                |
| 2023-08-11T11:01:00 | cpu1 | 0.2                |
| 2023-08-11T11:02:00 | cpu0 | 0.1                |
| 2023-08-11T11:02:00 | cpu1 | 0.2                |
+---------------------+------+--------------------+
```

Are there any other way to find the first (`time`, `usage_system`) data on each cpu?